# how can i export the geolocation output to log file?

Tags: javascript, php, html, geolocation

I have this code it displays the geolocation (Longitude: xx Latitude: xx Accuracy: xxx) ..how can I output the results into a log file log.txt when any body visit the url

```
    <!-- <xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"> -->
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//WAPFORUM//DTD XHTML Mobile 1.0//EN" "http://www.wapforum.org/DTD/xhtml-mobile10.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Geolocation API Demo</title>
<meta content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;" name="viewport"/>
<script>
function successHandler(location) {
    var message = document.getElementById("message"), html = [];
    html.push("<img width='512' height='512' src='http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=", location.coords.latitude, ",", location.coords.longitude, "&markers=size:small|color:blue|", location.coords.latitude, ",", location.coords.longitude, "&zoom=16&size=512x512&sensor=false' />");
    html.push("<p>Longitude: ", location.coords.longitude, "</p>");
    html.push("<p>Latitude: ", location.coords.latitude, "</p>");
    html.push("<p>Accuracy: ", location.coords.accuracy, " meters</p>");
    message.innerHTML = html.join("");
}
function errorHandler(error) {
    alert('Attempt to get location failed: ' + error.message);
}
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successHandler, errorHandler);
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="message">Location unknown</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you want to export using java or php.

Comment: you'll have to do it on the server side, send the object to the server and do whatever you want with it. JS doesnt have access to client/server filesystem

Comment: Do you want append the result of all users in same file? Saving a file via client side is not possible.

Comment: I want to export using php @Satya

Comment: No I would like to append the results in a separated file log.txt @NishantGhodke

Comment: I have a server side but i dont know how can i send the object to it :( @OriPrice

Comment: Separate files named log.txt doesn't make sense to me? File with same name cannot be stored in the same directory, new file will overwrite its data into new one. Do you want to download the files? Please elaborate.

Comment: @NishantGhodke just want to output the results into a text file that already exist in the same directory 'http://mysite/track/log.txt'

Comment: @NishantGhodke Thank you so much it works for me but,there is an output error with the log.txt file, it displays the latitude result like this ?3??553086 I dont know why

Comment: @NishantGhodke I tried to do that it displays now "Location unknown" :( and there is nothing being written inside log file

Comment: @NishantGhodke No its not the same results please there is something wrong i dont know ? :'(

Comment: Please share the link of your project.

Comment: @NishantGhodke can you see now inside the log.txt there is alot of misleading characters './?=<' on the numbers i dont know where they are came from

Comment: @NishantGhodke I have shared the link project please review

Comment: I have updated the PHP code, please try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the javascript code which will send the data asynchronously to the server.

```
    function successHandler(location) {
        var message = document.getElementById("message"), html = [];
        html.push("<img width='512' height='512' src='http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=", location.coords.latitude, ",", location.coords.longitude, "&markers=size:small|color:blue|", location.coords.latitude, ",", location.coords.longitude, "&zoom=16&size=512x512&sensor=false' />");
        html.push("<p>Longitude: ", location.coords.longitude, "</p>");
        html.push("<p>Latitude: ", location.coords.latitude, "</p>");
        html.push("<p>Accuracy: ", location.coords.accuracy, " meters</p>");
        message.innerHTML = html.join("");

        //Send this to server
        var xmlhttp;
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera
                xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
            } else { // code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }

            xmlhttp.open("POST","script.php",true);
            xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");
            xmlhttp.send("latitude="+location.coords.latitude+"&longitude="+location.coords.longitude+"&accuracy="+location.coords.accuracy); // pass data, assuming lat, long, acc are respective js variables
    }
    function errorHandler(error) {
        alert('Attempt to get location failed: ' + error.message);
    }
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successHandler, errorHandler);
```

Retrieve the data on server side and save with below PHP code (**script.php**)

```
<?php
    $latitude = $_POST['latitude'];
    $longitude = $_POST['longitude'];
    $accuracy = $_POST['accuracy'];

    $string = $latitude." - ".$longitude." | ".$accuracy; // this will turn into 00000 - 00000 | 0.25

    $myfile = file_put_contents('log.txt', $string.PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
?>
```

Comment: thank you so much but how can i call the java code into my server ? :(

Comment: I have updated my answer according to your need. Please try it.

Comment: Thank you so much it works for me but,there is an output error with the log.txt file, it displays the latitude result like this ?3??553086 I dont know why

Comment: Try debugging the js variables by using console.log(var_name); and see the output in console area of your browser. Compare the data send and data received. May be it is the same value you are receiving.

Answer (score 0):

For this you will need a server side that can store data locally on its system. I would suggest that you use PHP or whatever other server side language you know.

You will write a program that will receive an object, or perhaps just 2 variables and will store it into a file.txt.

This should not be very hard, if you are confused you should look up JavaScript AJAX calls.

Comment: I have server side but i dont know how can i call the object :(

Comment: You should be able to find out how to send data to PHP via an AJAX Call. Use google and you should be able to find an answer to your question. You dont need to send an object to the server, you can simply send 2 variables.

Answer (score 0):

For java here is the code.

```
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
        }
    }
            xmlhttp.open("POST","file.jsp?latitude="+location.coords.latitude+"&longitude="+location.coords.longitude+"&accuracy="+location.coords.accuracy,true);                
            xmlhttp.send();
```

In Jsp (file.jsp) write. Better to write java code in servlets not in JSP.

```
java.io.File file = new java.io.File("d://filename.log");
java.io.FileWriter writer = new java.io.FileWriter(file);
writer.write(request.getParameter("latitude")+" "+request.getParameter("longitude")+" "+request.getParameter("accuracy")); 
writer.flush();
writer.close();
```

Comment: thank you so much could you please write the full code :(

Comment: @Monica, use the above given ajax code in your script means in successHandler() function call.

Comment: I mean the java code and my code could you append them in one code please?

Comment: I tried to did that it tells now 'Location unknown' :(